# Finding a single irrational root to a rational function.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The function is: 
$$y={x^3 + 3x^2 + 6\over x-3}$$

I have to do a sketch and was able to find $y$-int, vertical asymptote, end behavior asymptote.  When searching for roots I used rational root theorem--of which there were none.  I used that synthetic division to determine lower and upper bounds of root ( $-6$ and $-3$ respectively)...but now I'm stuck.  Please help!

Comment: For the root, the division by $(x-3)$ doesn't matter. So you can just [use the formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula_for_roots) if you must know the actual expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can check there's a root between $-4$  and $-3$, so you can find an approximation of the root by dichotomy or Newton's method.

If you want the exact value of the root, use Cardano's method; it will work because we know there is only on real root (this is deduced from the variations $p(x)=x^+3x^2+6$):

1. Rewrite the equation in standard form (no term of degree $2$) by an appropriate change of variable:
   $$x^3+3x^2+6=(x+1)^3-3x-1+6=(x+1)^3-3(x+1)+8$$
   Setting $y=x+1$, we must solve $y^3-3y+8=0$.
2. Set $y=u+v$. The equation becomes:
   $$u^3+v^3+3uv(u+v) -3(u+v)+6=u^3+v^3 +3(u+v)(uv-1)+8=0.$$
   Since we now have two unknowns, we can impose a condition, in order to simplify the equation: $uv=1$. We obtain the (nonlinear)  system of equations:
   $$\begin{cases}u^3+v^3=-8\\uv=1\end{cases}\iff\begin{cases}u^3+v^3=-8\\u^3v^3=1\end{cases}$$
3. So we have to find first $u^3$ and $v^3$ knowing their sum $-8$ and their product $1$. This is a classical problem on quadratic equations, and we know $u^3, v^3$ are the roots of the equation:
   $$t^2+8t+1=0.$$
   We'll use the reduced formulae: $\Delta'=16-1=15$, so the roots are:
   $$u^3,v^3=-4\pm\sqrt{15}.$$
4. Finally we get:
   $$x=y-1=u+v-1 =-\sqrt[3]{4+\sqrt{15}}-\sqrt[3]{4-\sqrt{15}}-1.$$

Comment: Thank you Bernard, but right now I am crying because I have no idea what you are doing.  Is this a typical 11th grade pre-calculus process?

Comment: I don't know. Here in France, it's a typical exercise for good high school students. Not everyone has done it, though. Note that Cardano's method dates back to the Renaissance.